# Confusion between Set Equality and Isomorphism Proof Methods when dealing with Fields of Quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, ring-isomorphism

The common methods for proving $A = B$ and $A \approx B$ are very different. To prove a set equality $A = B$, the common method is to show that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$. For the former, we show that for any $a \in A$, $a$ also has properties which guarantee that $a \in B$, and likewise for the latter. Showing that two arbitrary rings $A \approx B$ is an entirely different process; generally a one-to-one, onto, and operation preserving isomorphism $\phi: A \to B$ must be found.

**Importantly, it seems as though it is impossible to 'swap' these proof techniques**. It doesn't make sense, to prove, say,

$$Z_{10} \approx Z_5 \otimes Z_2$$

By trying to show $Z_{10} \subset Z_5 \otimes Z_2$ and $Z_5 \otimes Z_2 \subset Z_{10}$, because, if interpreting these symbols literally, this is nonsensical. Showing that some $(a, b) \in Z_5 \otimes Z_2$ exists also in $Z_{10}$ makes no sense because the elements and operations don't match.

Which is why I'm wondering that **something like this seems to happen often in proofs relating to fields of quotients.**

For example, the question which I encountered which started this whole confusion.

> Let $Z[i]$ = $\{a + bi | a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Show that the field of quotients of $Z[i]$, $F$, is isomorphic to $Q[i] = \{a + bi | a, b \in \mathbb{Q}, b \ne 0\}$

This question has been asked on the Maths Stack Exchange before,and has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1037686/quotient-field-of-gaussian-integers).

The rough way that the proof goes, according to this answer (as well as the slightly different answer in the textbook itself) is as follows:

First, show that $Q[i] \subseteq F$. This is done by showing some $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d}i \in Q[i]$ can also be represented as a single fraction, $\frac{ad + cbi}{bd}$. It is now in the form of an element of $F$.

Second, show that $F \subseteq Q[i]$. This is done by showing some $\frac{a + bi}{c + di} \in F$ can, by multiplying by the conjugate, be represented like so:

$$\frac{ac + bd + (bc - ad)i}{c^2 + d^2} = \frac{ac + bd}{c^2 + d^2} + \frac{bc-ad}{c^2 + d^2}i \in Q[i]$$

At first glance this seems convincing, and I am sure that it is correct--but the more I seem to think about it, the less it makes sense. $F$, the field of quotients, is a set of *equivalency classes*, whilst $Q[i]$ is simply a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Isn't proceeding by the proof above, showing that $F \approx Q[i]$ by showing $Q[i] \subseteq F$ and $F \subseteq Q[i]$ just as absurd as the earlier example of showing $Z_{10} \approx Z_5 \otimes Z_2$ by showing $Z_{10} \subset Z_5 \otimes Z_2$ and $Z_5 \otimes Z_2 \subset Z_{10}$?

Phrased another way, how can we rigorously say that (in the first part of the proof)

$$\frac{ad + cbi}{bd} \in F$$

When the element on the left-hand side is some "number" from $Q[i] \subset \mathbb{C}$ and the right hand side is a set of equivalency classes? Isn't this as absurd as the statement "$(a, b) \in Z_{10}$"?

(A similar, but opposite, argument holds for the second part of the proof).

Comment: Do you find the definition of real numbers as [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) also "absurd"? It seems to me that often in mathematics we define objects of one kind using objects of a very different nature. To me, this only enhances the "mystery" rather than producing cognitive dissonance.

Comment: Formally speaking, $\mathbb Q\subseteq \mathbb R$ is also absurd, but $\mathbb Q$ is identified with a subfield of $\mathbb R$ so this abuse of notation makes sense.

Comment: @AlvinL So what you're saying is that the correct way of understanding is this: $Q[i] \subseteq F$ means that every element $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d}i$ in $Q[i]$ may be *represented in the form of* an element in $F$ (that is, $\frac{ad + cbi}{bd}$)? Similar to how it can be shown that $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ because each rational $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ can be *represented in the form of* an element in $\mathbb{R}$ (that is, a decimal)? And in mathematics, it is fair to equate the phrase "$\alpha$ may be represented in the form of an element in A" with "$\alpha \in A$"?

Comment: @adamdhalla that's the gist of it. There's an embedding from $\mathbb Q$ into $\mathbb R$ , so whenever one says $\mathbb Q\subseteq \mathbb R$, $\mathbb Q$ is to be regarded as the image of that embedding.